# Turbo C++ : while(fin) vs while(!fin.eof())

Tags: while-loop, turbo-c++, dosbox, data-files

I was told that I should be using `while(fin)` instead of `while(!fin.eof())` when reading a file.

What exactly is the difference?

**Edit:** I do know that `while(fin)` actually checks the stream object and that when it becomes NULL, the loop breaks and it covers eof and fail flags.
But my course teacher says that `fin.eof()` is better so I need to understand the fundamental operation that's going on here.

Which one is the right practice?

**Note:** This is not a duplicate, I need assistance in Turbo C++ and with binary files.
I'm basically trying to read a file using a class object.

Comment: Not the answer, but man, turbo C++ is old...

Comment: Compare the two choices when an error occurs while reading the file.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm looking for some theoretical explanation. I can of course check fin and fin.eof(). And it turns out that fin also checks for the fail flag along with the eof flag but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: @AlphaMineron In your comment you already describe what the difference is, so what are you asking for? It directly follows that `while(fin.eof())` will enter an endless loop if an error is encountered, while `while(fin)` exits the loop.

Comment: @CodesInChaos but I don't understand what I'm doing when I write while(fin)... my course book says that it means I'm checking the stream object and it becomes NULL. My teacher says: fin.eof() is better to use. I don't understand the fundamental operation which is going on between the two.... I wanna get back at my teacher, but I can't if I don't know the fundamental.

Comment: The stream object doesn't actually become null.  It enters an invalid state, and after that its `operator void*()` function returns null because it's in an invalid state.  (In modern C++, it's `explicit operator bool()` instead, but Turbo C++ is definitely not modern.)

Comment: In general you want to do neither. Test if your actual i/o is successful or not, don't check the state of the stream after the fact, and most likely after you've processed bad data.

Comment: @RetiredNinja what do you mean? How do I check if the actual I/O is successful or not without using the stream object?

Comment: `if(stream >> variable)`, `if(stream.read(...))` Functions have return values for a reason.

Comment: @RetiredNinja oh crap! Could you write an answer with a example code so I can close the question?

Comment: What is `fin` ?

Comment: @M.M Oh my bad, Its the stream object. `ifstream fin;` then `fin.open("file.dat", ios::binary);`

Comment: **Consider using some standard compliant C++11 compiler:** both [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C++ compilers much better than old and *obsolete* TurboC++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I am assuming `fin` is your `fstream` object. In which case your teacher would not have told you to use `while(fin.eof())` for reading from file. She would have told to use `while(!fin.eof())`.

Let me explain. `eof()` is a member of the `fstream` class which returns a `true` or `false` value depending on whether the End Of File (eof) of the file you are reading has been reached. Thus while `eof()` function returns `0` it means the end of file has not been reached and loop continues to execute, but when `eof()` returns `1` the end of the file has been reached and the loop exits.

`while(fin)` loop is entered because `fin` actually returns the value of an error flag variable inside the class object `fin` whose value is set to 0 when any function like read or write or open fails. Thus the loop works as long as the read function inside the loop works.

Personally I would not suggest either of them. 
I would suggest

//assume a class abc.

```
abc ob;


While(fin.read((char*)&ob, sizeof(ob)))
{}
```

Or

```
While(fin.getline(parameters))
{}
```

This loop reads the file record inside the loop condition and if nothing was read due to the end of file being reached, the loop is exited.

The problem with `while(!fin.eof())` is that it returns `1` if the end of file has been reached. End of file is actually a character that is put at the end of the file. So when the read function inside the loop reads this character and sets a variable eof to 1. All the function actually does is return this value.

Thus works fine when you are reading lines in words but when you are reading successive records of a class from a file, this method will fail.
Consider

```
clas abc
{}a;

Fstream fin("file");


While(!fin.eof())


{
  fin.read((char*)&a,sizeof(a));


  a.display();  // display is a member function which displays the info }
```

Thus displays the last record twice. This is because the end of file character is the character after the last byte of the last record. When the last is read the file pointer is at the eof byte but hasn't read it yet. So it will enter the loop again but this time the eof char is read but the read function fails. The values already in the variable `a`, that is the previous records will be displayed again.

Answer (score 0):

One good method is to do something like this:

```
while ( instream.read(...) && !instream.eof() ) {  //Reading a binary file
      Statement1;
      Statement2;
}
```

or in case of a text file:

```
while ( (ch = instream.get()) && !instream.eof() ) {  //To read a single character
      Statement1;
      Statement2;
}
```

Here, the object is being read within the while loop's condition statement and then the value of **eof** flag is being tested.
This wouldn't result in undesired outputs.

Here we are checking the status of the actual I/O operation and the eof together. You may also check for the fail flag.

I would like to point out that according to @RetiredNinja, we may only check for the I/O operation. 
That is:

```
while ( instream.read(...) ) {  //Reading a binary file
      Statement1;
      Statement2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy workaround that worked for me to avoid any problems when using eof is to check for it after the first reading and not as a condition of the while loop itself. Something like this:

```
 while (true) // no conditions
 {
    filein >> string; // an example reading, could be any kind of file reading instruction

    if (filein.eof()) break; // break the while loop if eof was reached

    // the rest of the code
 }
```